# Grunt, Jasmine, Phantom, React Unit Testing: React throws on ReactElementValidator

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jasmine, phantomjs, reactjs

I'm using `Grunt` to run `Jasmine` unit tests with `Phantom`.

```
Grunfile.js
module.exports = function (grunt)
{
    "use strict";

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');

    grunt.initConfig(
        {
            pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
            browserify: {
                dev: {
                    files: {
                        'test-output.js':['src/methods.js']
                    },
                    options: {
                        browserifyOptions: {
                            debug: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            karma:
            {
                unit:{
                    configFile:"karma.conf.js"
                }
            }
        });
};
```

with this `Karma` config file

```
module.exports = function(config)
{
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['browserify', 'jasmine'],
        files: [
            'myDir/*.js'
        ],
        exclude: [
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            'myDir/*.js':['browserify','reactify']
        },
        reporters: ['progress'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: false,
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        browserify: {
            debug: true,
            transform: []
        },
        plugins: [
            'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine','karma-bro'],
        singleRun: true
    });
};
```

React is installed locally as a package in the `node_modules` folder.  I can `grunt browserify` and everything gets bundled into `test-ouput.js` as expected, but when I do `grunt karma` I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'ReactElementValidator.createElement.bind
```

If I inspect the `test-ouput.js` file I can see that the `ReactElementValidator.createElement.bind` function is inside of the bundle.  Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: I think there is a *inown* issue with using the React Test Utilities inside PhantomJS.  Just looking for a reference.  Fairly certain this is the real issue: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522.

Comment: Looks to be fixed in PhantomJS 2.x, but I haven't tried it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This a know issue with phantomJS < 2.0. To fix this simply install phantomjs polyfill like this:

```
npm install --save-dev phantomjs-polyfill
```

And add it to the config like this.

```
files: [
    'node_modules/phantomjs-polyfill/bind-polyfill.js',
    'myDir/*.js'
]
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: should be marked as answer - confirmed solving the problem

Comment: For people getting stuck, please note the order in which this is added into the "files" array matters. It should be first. Spend quite some time on that. 0_0